# I don't understand why such a things happen with job_start in Vim script?

Tags: vim

Executing `job_start` with file option gets results in files.

For example,

```
function hoge()
  let cmd = 'grep -nr hoge .'
  let option = { 'exit_cb': function('s:aaa'),
          \ 'out_io': 'file',
          \ 'out_name': '~/test'}
  call job_start(['/bin/sh', '-c', cmd], option)
endfunction
```

then, open ~/test and can see results of grep.

But in case of code with rubocop instead of grep, I can't see results.
The ~/test file is empty.

```
function hoge()
  let cmd = 'rubocop'
  let option = { 'exit_cb': function('s:aaa'),
          \ 'out_io': 'file',
          \ 'out_name': '~/test'}
  call job_start(['/bin/sh', '-c', cmd], option)
endfunction
```

But if with `close_cb` option, I can see results.
The ~/test file is written results of rubocop.

```
function hoge()
  let cmd = 'rubocop'
  let option = { 'exit_cb': function('s:aaa'),
          \ 'close_cb': function('s:bbb'),
          \ 'out_io': 'file',
          \ 'out_name': '~/test'}
  call job_start(['/bin/sh', '-c', cmd], option)
endfunction
```

I don't understand why those differences happen.
When `close_cb` option is needed?

Comment: not familiar with the ruby command. very likely, the data to write is buffered